# 0xC000001D: Illegal Instruction when running cvHaarDetectObjects opencv

Tags: opencv

I get 0xC000001D: Illegal Instruction when running cvHaarDetectObject. Below is my code

```
int main() {

IplImage* img;
img = cvLoadImage( "lena.jpg",1);

CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad( "haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml" );


static CvScalar colors[] = { {{0,0,255}}, {{0,128,255}}, {{0,255,255}}, 
{{0,255,0}}, {{255,128,0}}, {{255,255,0}}, {{255,0,0}}, {{255,0,255}} };

// Detect objects
cvClearMemStorage( storage );
CvSeq* objects = cvHaarDetectObjects( img, cascade, storage, 1.1, 2, 0, cvSize(40, 40) );

CvRect* r;
// Loop through objects and draw boxes
for( int i = 0; i < (objects ? objects->total : 0 ); i++ ){
    r = ( CvRect* )cvGetSeqElem( objects, i );
    cvRectangle( img, cvPoint( r->x, r->y ), cvPoint( r->x + r->width, r->y + r->height ),
        colors[i%8]);
}

cvNamedWindow( "Output" );
cvShowImage( "Output", img );
cvWaitKey();


cvReleaseImage( &img );

return 0;
}
```

Is it something wrong with setup? I can compile the code, but when i run it, i get illegal instruction error, when the program run until cvHaarDetectObjects.

I have included all the lib files and place image inside the same directory of my project.

I'm using VS2010, Opencv2.4.3

Thanks and Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

I was working with this exact example this morning and just fixed this error.

First, my storage was erroring so I made it bigger (64MB instead of the default, which I think remember looking up was 64KB). That fixed my first allocation error, but the cvHaarDetectObjects() one was still happening. Note that you may/probably don't have to do this.

Next, I copy-pasted the part where it shows the image up above the cvHaarDetectObjects() call:

```
cvNamedWindow( "Output" );
cvShowImage( "Output", img );
cvWaitKey();

// Detect objects
cvClearMemStorage( storage );
CvSeq* objects = cvHaarDetectObjects( img, cascade, storage, 1.1, 2, 0, cvSize(40, 40) );
```

It showed that my image was not loading! Once I was sure the image I had showed up there, I moved it back down and ran the code as a whole -- it worked like a charm.

If that doesn't help, I would suggest doing a similar trace of every variable that is going into cvHaarDetectObjects() in order to see which one is not allocated correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..

How to i make my storage bigger using visual studio 2010?
I move the image loading on top of cvHaarDetectObjects, i found that the image unable to show up if i remove cvWaitKey(), is this the problem? Do i need cvWaitKey()?

Thanks and best regard